# Преобразование одного stateFlow в другой

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь преобразовать `Flow<List<CurrencyDB>>` в`StateFlow<List<Currency>>`?
В результате Flow содержит Any.
Подскажите что я делаю не так или подскажите лучший вариант преобразования.

```
@Entity(tableName = "currency_table")
data class CurrencyDB (
    @PrimaryKey
    val name: String,
    val value: Double,
    val favorite: Boolean
)

data class CurrencyDB (
    val name: String,
    val value: Double,
    val favorite: Boolean
)
```

```
fun transformerFlow(
        flow: Flow<List<CurrencyDB>>, scope: CoroutineScope
    ): Flow<List<Currency>?>{
        return flow.mapLatest {
            val list = mutableListOf<Currency>()
            for (i in it.indices) {
                list.add(
                    Currency(
                        name = it[i].name,
                        value = it[i].value,
                        favorite = it[i].favorite
                    )
                )
            }
        }.stateIn(
            scope = scope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            initialValue = listOf<Currency>()
        )
    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно что-то типа `stateFlow.map { converter.convert(it) }.stateIn(...)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб абсолютно прав. оператор map{...} преобразует каждый объект потока в то, что укажите. вы можете так же указать в каком потоке будет происходить преобразование указав .map{...}.flowOn("нужный Dispatcher")

Comment: p.s. на выходе у всех таких оператов на выходе ВСЕГДА просто Flow. это не будет холодным потоком, вы даже можете проверить, что он внутри и правда остается MutableStateFlow.

Comment: p.p.s. а откуда у вас взялся MutableFlow из Room? хороший тон, даже когда БД возвращает просто Flow (он под капотом тоже будет горячим)

Comment: У вас не работает ваш код, т.к. вы ничего не возвращаете из mapLatest (кстати, почему именно mapLatest, а не просто map?). Напишите в к конце лямбды `list` и должно начать работать. И да, этот ваш метод - лишний и всё сильно усложняет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Тоже заметил, что код в не метода работает, если обернуть в метод, то перестает.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: Надо весь код смотреть. Возможно у вас какие-то общедоступные переменные меняются, что создаёт видимость правильной работы кода)